# How do you group a picture and a table in Word 2016?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-word-2016

I am working through an issue with graphics that need to be translated in Word but I cannot change the original image. Is there a way to layer a table over a graphic and keep them locked together?  The Group function is grayed out when I select both elements. I have tried creating the combined elements in Word and PowerPoint but when I paste into my document, the two pieces move independently, even with an achor applied.

Answer (score 0):

To put a picture behind the table use the "Text Wrapping", "Behind text" option.

To position it under the table anchor it to the first cell in the table using "Position" "Vertical" below "Paragraph", drag the achor to the first cell.